# Buscar números repetidos em lista com Visualg

Tags: array, portugol, visualg

> Escreva um programa que recebe 100 números digitados pelo usuário. Ao final o programa exibe quantos números informados são iguais ao último número digitado.

Até onde eu conseguir fazer:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 30/05/2017
// Seção de Declarações 
var
vet:vetor[1..10] de inteiro
NUM,i,igual:INTEIRO
inicio
Para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
   Escreva("Digite um numero: ")
   Leia(num)
fimpara
para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
   se(num = vet[5])entao
       igual <- num + vet[10]
   fimse
fimpara
Escreva(igual)
fimalgoritmo
```

Como eu faço para comparar os valores e mostrar quantos números são iguais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 30/05/2017
// Seção de Declarações 
var
vet:vetor[1..100] de inteiro
i, igual : INTEIRO
inicio
Para i <- 1 ate 100 faca
   Escreva("Digite um numero: ")
   Leia(vet[i])
fimpara
para i <- 1 ate 99 faca
   se (vet[i] = vet[100]) entao
       igual <- igual + 1
   fimse
fimpara
Escreva(igual)
fimalgoritmo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Unique.ptg).

Se o último for o anterior aí deve mudar esta linha:

```
   se (vet[i] = vet[i + 1]) entao
```