# Como faço para determinar o número que aparece mais vezes e a posição em que se encontra?

Tags: array, portugol

Foi realizada a leitura de um vetor de n posições, como faço para determinar o numero que aparece mais e a posição em que se encontra?

```
programa {
    funcao inicio(){
        inteiro vetor[]
        inteiro numero, conta
        inteiro i, j, n

        leia(n)
        para (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            leia(vetor[i])
        }

        para (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            para (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                se (vetor[i] == vetor[j] e i != j){

                    escreva("numeros repetido ", vetor[i], " posição ", i,", ", j, "\n")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Não consigo determinar qual é o número que se repete mais, o que consegui determinar é onde há repetidos.

Comment: E qual o problema? No que podemos ajudar?

Comment: Que linguagem de programação é essa? Como vc é usuário novo, aconselharia a fazer um tour [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208891/buscar-n%C3%BAmeros-repetidos-em-lista-com-visualg

Comment: Opa bom dia, tenta criar outro vetor e depois escreve o valor da posição do v1 e no v2 tu usa apenas de contador . Se não conseguir avisa aqui nos coments que eu posto a solução

Answer (score 0):

Minha resolução, utilizei dois vetores de 5 posições em `vetor1[5]` e `vetor2[5]` porque se não, não compilava logo a leitura de *n* terá que ser obrigatoriamente 5, mas fica a ideia que da para mudar em cima

```
programa {

    funcao inicio(){
        // Declaração de variaveis
        inteiro vetor1[5], vetor2[5], n, chave, maior, j=1, i
        logico mensagem = verdadeiro

        // Leitura de n
        leia(n)

        // leitura do vetor principal
        para(i=1; i<n; i++){
            leia(vetor1[i])
        }

        // Vetor 2 define as repitições, deixando primeiro todas iguais a 0
        para(i=1; i<n; i++){
            vetor2[i] = 0
        }

        // Verifica se dois numeros são iguais e se sim aumenta no vetor repetições
        para(i=1; i<n; i++){
            para(j=1; j<n; j++){
                se (vetor1[i] == vetor1[j]){
                    vetor2[i] = vetor2[i] + 1
                }
            }
        }
        // Determina qual é o maior nº de repetições
        maior = 0
        para(i=1; i<n; i++){
            se(vetor2[i] > maior){
                maior = vetor2[i] 
            }
        }
        // Determina em que posições esta repetido e depois qual é o numero repetido
        para(i=1; i<n; i++){
            se (vetor2[i] == maior){
                chave = i
                // Utilizado o ciclo while para não repetir a mensagem o nº de vezes de repetições do vetor 2 
                enquanto(mensagem == verdadeiro){
                    escreva("\nNumero mais repetido: ", vetor1[chave], " e repete ", maior, " vezes")
                    mensagem = falso
                }
                escreva("\nPosições: ", i)
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Aqui vai a solução do problema em Python 3:

```
def mais_repetido(array):
    s = set(array)
    d = {}

    for i in s:
        d[i] = 0

    for i in s:
        for j in array:
            if i == j:
                d[i] += 1

    maior = max(d.values())
    chave = 0

    for i in d:
        if d[i] == maior:
            chave = i
            break

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] == chave:
            print('Posição: {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: O ideal não seria que a resposta seja em portugol já que a questão é referente a isso?

Comment: Você pode pegar o algoritmo e transcrever para Portugol :)

Comment: E será que o usuário tem conhecimento tanto em `Python` quanto em `Portugol` para fazer isso?

Comment: Bem, tentei ajudar, até mais

Comment: @R.Santos no caso, respostas em demais linguagens devem ser bem vindas, até porque se alguém encontrar o mesmo problema com Python terá base para resolver. Também tem o lado de que alguém poderia traduzir para Portugol e por como resposta